# Auto increment by 2 for a specific table (No php handeling)

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have a table created that I need to switch the auto increment to +2 for every entry. I have found a way to do it globaly by:

```
 setting auto increment=2
auto increment offset=2
```

Can I do this for one table only?

Answer (score 0):

[auto_increment_offset](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_offset) will only set the starting point for all tables, not the increment.

AUTO_INCREMENT in a table definition or alter statement will set the starting auto_increment number for that single table.

What you are looking for is more like the [server setting auto_increment_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html#sysvar_auto_increment_increment).  Unfortunately, that is not supported on a single table within MySQL.  To quote the manual:

[It is not possible to confine the effects of these two variables to a single table, and thus they do not take the place of the sequences offered by some other database management systems; these variables control the behavior of all AUTO_INCREMENT columns in all tables on the MySQL server.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-master.html)

You could try rolling your own sequence, having a separate auto_increment "sequence" table that you insert into every time you insert into this table, just take the last_insert_id() from the sequence table and multiply it by 2 for your other tables use.